# Spring MVC @RequestParam -- multiple key names? or another way to require "one or the other"

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

What is the best way to allow multiple names for query parameters? I have a web service which has changed parameter names, but must continue for a while to accept the old names.

I'm loath to create 2 RequestParams, both not required, b/c I do require one or the other to be present. Something like this would be sweet:

```
@RequestParam(value = "startTime|start", required = true ) String startTime,
```

rather than

```
@RequestParam(value = "startTime", required = false ) String startTime,
@RequestParam(value = "start", required = false ) String start ){
if ( start != null || startTime != null ){ //  ...
```

Is there any way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: I think the only option is the second one :S.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do something like this (create a proxy method that will intercept the "old" calls and transfer them to the new method):

```
@RequestMapping(value="/your-mapping", params = {"oldparam1", "oldparam2", ...})
public Whatever yourOldMethod(@RequestParam(value="oldparam1", required=true) String oldParam1, ...){
   return yourNewMethod(oldParam1, ...);
}

@RequestMapping(value="/your-mapping", params = {"newparam1", "newparam1", ...})
public Whatever yourNewMethod(@RequestParam(value="newparam1", required=true) String oldParam1, ...){
   //do whatever you need to do here
}
```

When you don't need to support the old calls, simply delete `yourOldMethod`.

The beauty here, is using the `"params"` of `@RequestMapping`, thus allowing 2 methods to listen to the same `"URL"` (with different params for each)

Comment: Thanks. This will get ugly still since I have multiple pairs of names in the same function unfortunately its not old vs new. But I'll suck it up and handle the combos.